# how to display arraylist items in toast?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-toast

I am using json parsing,i am sending five emails and five names and in response it gives

```
{
    "invitefriend": [
        {

            "message": "Friend Request sent to : abc"
        },
        {

            "message": "Friend Request sent to : def"
        }
    ]
}
```

now what i am trying is i want to get abc and def in toast,but it gives one by one seperatly

```
 JSONArray jsonary=json.getJSONArray("invitefriend");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonary.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jsonary.getJSONObject(i);
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                // map.put(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_ID, c.getString(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_ID));
                map.put(TAG_SUCCESS_INVITE,c.getString(TAG_SUCCESS_INVITE));
                map.put(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE, c.getString(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE));

                ArrayList<String> msgs=new ArrayList<String>();
                msgs=map.put(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE, c.getString(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE));
                System.out.println("MESSAGE : " + msg);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList

               getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+msgs, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                data.add(map);
            }
```

Comment: You are using Toast within the for loop so it is displaying the Toast one by one. Just take the Toast outside the loop :)

Comment: Additionally, you can `Toast` your `ArrayList` `msgs.toString()` directly. Both `ArrayList`'s and `HashMap`'s `toString()` methods return readable output.

Comment: @MikeM. can you paste as answer

Comment: @Jolly Sure thing. Gimme a minute. I'm on a phone atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting multiple `Toast`s because you're `Toast`ing inside the `for` loop. Simply move that call to outside the loop:

```
JSONArray jsonary=json.getJSONArray("invitefriend");
ArrayList<String> msgs=new ArrayList<String>();
String msg = null;

for (int i = 0; i < jsonary.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = jsonary.getJSONObject(i);
    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    // map.put(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_ID, c.getString(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_ID));
    map.put(TAG_SUCCESS_INVITE,c.getString(TAG_SUCCESS_INVITE));
    map.put(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE, c.getString(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE));

    msg=map.put(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE, c.getString(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE));
    msgs.add(msg);
    System.out.println("MESSAGE : " + msg);

    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    data.add(map);
}

getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msgs.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Also, we've defined the `ArrayList` `msgs` to collect the response messages, which we `Toast` directly with `msgs.toString()`.

Comment: Um, your current code won't compile as you have it posted. I'd suggest how to fix it, but now I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. Is it `data` that you want to Toast?

Comment: Ok, I think I see where you're going. I've shuffled some things in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
   JSONArray jsonary=json.getJSONArray("invitefriend");
    ArrayList<String> msgs;
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonary.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jsonary.getJSONObject(i);
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                // map.put(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_ID, c.getString(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_ID));
                map.put(TAG_SUCCESS_INVITE,c.getString(TAG_SUCCESS_INVITE));
                map.put(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE, c.getString(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE));

                msgs = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());

                System.out.println("MESSAGE : " + msgs);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList


                data.add(map);
            }
           getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),msgs,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: incompitable types..required arraylist found string

Comment: where are you getting this error? Also there is msgs and msg in your code correct it to msgs.

Comment: msgs=map.put(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE, c.getString(TAG_SUCCESS_MESSAGE)); near this line i am getting error

Comment: Your code is fundamentally incorrect ,map.put() returns a null or a key. In your case it is returning the key which is a String. And you are appending a String to a ArrayList...hence it is giving error.

Comment: the response item "message"i am getting,i want that in toast..how to get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95108/discussion-between-jolly-and-parag-kadam).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do ""+array list Then it will display all array list items in toast. Or if you need all one by one,then take a for loop with length of array list in that u just add array list[i]like

```
for (int i=0;i<=arraylist.length;i++){

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),arraylist[i],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: you mean i need one more for loop?to display all items in single toast?

Comment: i want abc and def with comma seperate in single toast

Comment: just do this ->Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+arraylist[i],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); outside the loop.

Comment: You just typecast arraylist to string as parag kadam said..
Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+arraylist[i],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+msgs,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
then u will get all values in toast.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this. i think its helpfull

```
featured_list = new ArrayList<Featured>();
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), object.getString("thumb").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```